# Jade can't read variable on jade file

Tags: express, pug

I'm using express.js + jade and have a problem with reading variables.

**/index.js**

```
var boardgame={
grids:['a','b','c'],
winer: 'No'
}
var jfile=JSON.stringify(boardgame);
res.render('index2', { title: 'Tic Tac Toe', date: today, player: name, gb:jfile});
```

**/index.jade**

```
script(type='text/javascript').
        // Pass as regular array here
        var inews = JSON.parse('!{gb}')
        var grids = inews.grids
        var grid1 = grids[0]
        var winner = inews.winer
        var ha ="a"
        console.log(winner);
h1= grid1
h1= ha
```

There is nothing to show up on the web, but there is a "No" from the winner in the console. I don't really know what the problem is now.

Please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing pug server-side execution and client-side execution.

When you have a `script.` tag in your pug template everything in there is going to get sent down to the browser and will be executed there if it is formed correctly.

When you use the equals sign in a tag, such as `h1= grid1` that is going to be evaluated by pug on the server.

So, you are trying to access a client-side variable (`grid1`) in a server-side context.  That variable doesn't exist in pug and will render `undefined` which is why you're getting nothing in the browser window.

You would need to pass the actual object instead of a stringified version through to the template in order to render it as you want:

```
res.render('index2', { title: 'Tic Tac Toe', date: today, player: name, gb:boardgame});
```

Then you could do this in your pug template as the variable would be available to the template's execution context:

```
h1= gb.grids[0]
```